# Group comparison for bivariate distributions

Tags: nonparametric, density-function, group-differences, kernel-smoothing

For two groups A and B that consist of n and m individual samples. Each individual sample has a unique 2-dimensional joint probability density functions (PDFs)of two variables. These PDFs are estimated by kernel density estimation (KDE).

If I want to treat each PDF from each individual subject as an independent observation, which statistical tests can be used to assess whether there are significant local differences in PDF estimates from individuals in group A and group B?

Comment: Welcome to the site. This question is both a bit confusing and very broad. Please ask more specific questions.

Comment: I second Peter's comment. Just to get the straight: Does every individual has its own different bivariate KDE or just every individual has two measurements and all the individuals together form a KDE?